# Why doesn't debian GCC use now-binding when compile with "-no-pie"?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, debian

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("hello world\n");
}
```

```
$ gcc -o no-pie test.c -no-pie
$ gcc -o default test.c
$ 
$ readelf -a ./no-pie | grep "NOW"
$ 
$ readelf -a ./default | grep "NOW"
 0x000000000000001e (FLAGS)              BIND_NOW
 0x000000006ffffffb (FLAGS_1)            Flags: NOW PIE
$ 
$
```

Why doesn't debian GCC use now-binding when compile with "-no-pie" ?

I found this while researching the "-no-pie" option's involvement in binding.

https://salsa.debian.org/toolchain-team/gcc/-/blob/f5025396e1994512fecc7558a29891cc66dc0fe6/debian/patches/bind_now_when_pie.diff

```
$ strings `which gcc` | grep "\-z now"
... %{static|shared|r:;!no-pie:-pie -z now} ...
```

That diff seems to add "-pie -z now" when there is no no-pie option.

What are the security or performance benefits of using lazy-binding when not using PIE?